# recursive curl -l to get end state of a webpage

Tags: command-line, curl, url

I desire to know if a certain webpage returns the 200/OK HTTP status code (HSC). Of course, I can the **first** HSC of a webpage by doing `curl -l URL`.

The problem is that many webpages has redirections, and `curl` doesn't naturally flow with these redirections, so it stops in he first HSC, not continuing to the **last** HSC and returns:

> 301: Moved permanently

This does not help me to know, if the **last** webpage that a user would be moved to is good or not, or just if it returns 200 or not.

How could I make sure `curl` keeps going with the URL and redirections (if there are any) till it reaches the last url to check it return 200 or not?

The purpose is to know if a user should reache a typical webpage in the end (200/OK), or not.

Comment: This will follow any redirects: `curl -L mywebpage.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow redirects use the `-L` flag:

```
curl -L mywebpage.com
```

Manpage of curl:

```
-L, --location
              (HTTP/HTTPS) If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated  with  a  Location:  header  and  a  3XX
              response  code),  this  option will make curl redo the request on the new place. If used together with -i, --include or -I, --head, headers from
              all requested pages will be shown. When authentication is used, curl only sends its credentials to the initial host. If a redirect takes curl to
              a  different  host, it won't be able to intercept the user+password. See also --location-trusted on how to change this. You can limit the amount
              of redirects to follow by using the --max-redirs option.

              When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with a  GET  if  the
              HTTP  response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response code was any other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following request using the same unmodi‐
              fied method.

              You can tell curl to not change the non-GET request method to GET after a 30x response by using  the  dedicated  options  for  that:  --post301,
              --post302 and -post303.
```

Comment: Thus the end command should be `curl -L -l URL` I assume.

Comment: Yes, I believe so!